# Fetching URL through proxy returns 403 error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

With the goal of avoiding all the CORS headaches, I setup my vue cli to proxy the API call through webpack:

**config/index.js**

```
proxyTable: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'https://remote',
    changeOrigin: true,
    '^/api': '/api'
  }
},
```

Visiting the URL directly in browser works, for example: `http://localhost:8080/api/events`

However, if I try to fetch the url with axios, I get a 403 error: 
`Error: "Request failed with status code 403"`

Unfortunately the only reference I could find is [this open issue](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1453).

In my case, it doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome.

This is a vue-cli 2 project, axios `0.18.0`, vue `2.5.2, webpack`3.6.0`, webpack-dev-server`2.9.1`

Answer (score 2):

Ah I see, in case it benefits anyone, for some reason, setting my API url as localhost was not working:

**.env**

`API_URL=//localhost:8080/api`

But the following works:

**.env**

`API_URL=//127.0.0.1:8080/api`